# Can not pass VERY BIG (HEAVY) UIImage to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have problem of passing image of size approximately `300 MB` to another `UIViewController`. I can pass any other images, but their size are not so big.

Firstly I call `UIImagePickerController` in my first `UIViewController`, after picking the image I show preview window in second `UIViewController`. Tried to use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` key, but also not works.

My code looks like:

1) Second `UIViewController` to pass image

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *selectedImage;
@end
```

2) In my first UIViewController

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    SecondViewController *vc = [SecondViewController new];
    vc.selectedImage = selectedImage;

    [imagePickerController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finishedToPickImage) name:@"finishedToPickImage" object:nil];
}
```

It is possible to do it without compressing original image?

Comment: What error did you get? I thought since the `UIImage` was already resided in the memory, and you passed it by reference, there should be no data copying at all given that you could fit the image in the memory in the first place. Did you try to present it in `UIImageView` or sth?

Comment: Yes, after passing image I put it into UIImageView, but image not showing. With breakpoint I can see that image not nil, but something like not fully loaded.

Comment: So, I believe that you could pass `UIImage` to the other view controller just fine because it was passed by reference. But the problem was the performance hit you get when trying to present it in `UIImageView`. `UIImageView` doc also states that there might be a performance hit if you use large image and should prescale it first https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/index.html

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks for advice, I'll try to solve it by decreasing size/quiality of the image

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    selectedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

    SecondViewController *vc = [SecondViewController new];
    vc.selectedImage = selectedImage;

    [imagePickerController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finishedToPickImage) name:@"finishedToPickImage" object:nil];
}
```

Try this code use UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage this will make the image size small.

Comment: **[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]** returns nil for me. I don't present edit window after picking, just preview.

Comment: UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  
  picker.allowsEditing = YES;

You haven't set allowsEditing set it to YES then try.

Comment: I just do not permit user to edit. So instead of editing window, I show my custom **UIViewController** to preview image. Therefore your approach do not sutisfy my needs.